# Get only unique item from the Line Odoo13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have this issue where items can be duplicated, but I want to get only unduplicated items and sum the quantity of them as in the pic below. for instance, I have 7 items in the line but they are 2 because the desk item I have 4 copies of It and the    boxW00009 I have 3 copies of it. I want to treat them as singular and calculate the quantity of 2, not 7. If the user added a new item and it is not duplicated I want to add its quantity too.
here is my code:

```
 @api.depends('move_line_ids.item_id')
def get_item_number(self):
    """
    Compute the unique items.
    """
    for rec in self:
        qyt = 0
        for line in rec.move_line_ids.mapped('item_id'):
            qyt += line.quantity
        rec.update({
            'item_number': qyt,
        })
```

here the pic
[image]

Comment: You just want the count or number of items of all lines? Just use `len(rec.move_line_ids.mapped('item_id'))`, because `mapped` will get you a recordset with exactly 2 items (item_id).

Comment: I want the number of unique items(for instance in the line they are 7 but actually they are duplicated from a uniqueness perspective they are 2 I want these 2). I have tried your solution it gives me this 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: What is behind `item_id`?

Comment: Oh wait, you don't need to loop on it! Just `rec.item_number = len(rec.move_line_ids.mapped('item_id'))` nothing more in your for loop on `self`.

Comment: rec.item_number = len(rec.move_line_ids.mapped('item_id')) this gives me all lines which is 7 but I want it to give 2 unique items

Comment: Then pls answer me question, what is behind `item_id`?

Comment: it is just like product_id. It's many2one relation from another model. Many items may have the same name but each one has a unique serial number

Comment: You can see 4 "desk" entries on the screenshot. Is everyone the same ID (item_id)?

Comment: No the same name but different id

Comment: you can see there is some call Source of document(W0008, W0009) and it is also duplicated. every item belongs to a specific source. every source has many items when I select one item before I save I should add all the items belonging to that source if W0008 has 8 desks this line should contain 8 desks and so on.

Comment: Sorry it is very difficult to understand the whole structure behind everything. If `item_id` means the column "Item" in your screenshot and `mapped` is not returning a recordset with exactly 2 items, then the name means nothing in that column. You could also try `len(rec.move_line_ids.mapped('item_id.name'))` if `name` is the correct field for the shown value. Atleast then `mapped` should return a list with exactly two strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onchange` method for `product_id` and filter  `self.product_id.order_id.order_line` if `product_id` is on it add +1 to `product_uom_qty`. Then set `self.product_id` False.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with python '|=' operator to prepare unique data by looping out of all the records, then you can sum the value.